# Can an HTTP server respond with a 404 to conceal the existence of a resource?

Tags: http, http-status-code-404

There may be cases where a client that doesn't have authorization to access a resource should be told that it doesn't exist instead of being told they aren't authorized. If a server does this, is it technically a violation of HTTP 1.1?

Comment: Irrespective of the existence/non-existence of a resource, when a user is un-authorized and you tell just that, will that itself not conceal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the RFC that forces you to tell the client the truth every time.

In the end it boils down to how you want the people behind the browser to react to a certain response. If you would send a `403 Forbidden` the user would know they may not access this resource (and no authentication window would open automatically). If you instead were to send a `404 Not Found` they could think to themselves that the server operator (you) made an error.

Your choice.